# Firebase Cloud Functions vs Firebase mobile native SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm planning to use Firebase Cloud Firestore for my native iOS and Android app. I'm wondering which approach makes more sense:

Option 1) Use Firebase iOS and Android native SDK to add data

or

Option 2) Use Cloud Functions (nodejs) to add data, and expose it as a REST API for iOS and Android devices to call it. Will this be more easier to maintain?

In iOS:

```
// Add a new document in collection "cities"
db.collection("cities").document("LA").setData([
    "name": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "CA",
    "country": "USA"
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error writing document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully written!")
    }
}
```

In Android:

```
Map<String, Object> city = new HashMap<>();
city.put("name", "Los Angeles");
city.put("state", "CA");
city.put("country", "USA");

db.collection("cities").document("LA")
        .set(city)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
            }
        });
```

In Node.js

```
var data = {
  name: 'Los Angeles',
  state: 'CA',
  country: 'USA'
};

// Add a new document in collection "cities" with ID 'LA'
var setDoc = db.collection('cities').doc('LA').set(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which one suits you better. However, using the Firebase Cloud Firestore native SDK will give you a direct client connection to the server where you will interact with the API directly. The tutorials are well documented for Android as well as for iOS development. Otherwise, you will have to expose an HTTP Cloud Function that will be triggered every time you want to perform an interaction with the database.

Also keep in mind that Cloud Functions have their own execution time and delays based on the `Memory allocation`. This means, that using the direct Firestore native SDK is much faster than going through a Cloud Function and you can also catch possible errors directly from the application rather than having to read the Cloud Function's LOGs.